# Emacs function: [pre] marked region [post]

Tags: function, emacs, latex, yasnippet

Selecting region, how to get a (pre)defined part before and after region?

Let's say for instance, working with LaTeX, we want `\begin{frame}{}` before the **region** and `\end{frame}` after region, how to get this done with Emacs by one function?

```
    [pre-part]"Has to be around this"[post-part]
```

I would encourage use of yasnippet. Also, maybe "autopare" can give a hint, since somehow it smartly can put quote signs around the marked region when pressing ".

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't just use yasnippet.  Was the documentation not clear that this functionality is provided?  If so, you should file a bug on github.

Comment: I was not aware of the documentation. I was actually looking before how to mix some lisp power with yasnippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use yasnippet.  Here is an example for an html tag snippet that can
wrap or not.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: Wrap open close tags
# binding: C-c C-t
# expand-env: ((yas-wrap-around-region t))
# --
<$1>$0</${1:$(car (split-string text))}>
```

This works with the latest github version of yasnippet.

Answer (score 2):

In latex-mode, `C-c C-o` does just that.

Comment: Not working for me, even after turning off the outline mode and saving .emacs (C-c C-o C-l being outline mode). Curious to this functionality, though event_jr answered the question.

Comment: My guess is that you're not using latex-mode (the latex mode bundled with Emacs) by LaTeX-mode provided by AUCTeX, in which case I think the binding is `C-c C-e` instead, if memory serves.

Comment: Using AUCTeX. I tested it, and yes it does work. Personally, I'm not a fan of that way of inserting an environment generally (I write snippets for everything), though this would be a good way of using it.